# Selecting and deleting duplicated rows for particular columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an sql table that saves **Locations**,

```
ID  Name   X     Y     Z
-------------------------
1   Loc1   12   24    45
2   Loc2   12   24    60
3   Loc3   54   32    33
4   Loc4   54   32    64
5   Loc5   98   66    90
6   Loc6   98   66    77
7   Loc7   44   50    98
```

Some Location coordinates (x and y) are duplicated by mistake

I want to select and delete one of them.

```
ID  Name   X     Y     Z
-------------------------
1   Loc1   12   24    45
2   Loc3   54   32    33
3   Loc5   98   66    90
4   Loc7   44   50    98
```

Is this possible with sql query?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Which one do you want to get rid of? For example Loc1 and Loc2 have the same values for X and Y. Why is Loc1 kept and Loc2 not kept?

Comment: Use rownumber partition by X for that ... and delete where rownum is greater then 1, after that goes with plain rownumber to update Name

Comment: Loc1 or Loc2 not important. You may dalete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the alter-table command and just drop the whole column.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Comment: why to drop column ?

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte
as
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by x,y order by x) as rn
)
delete from cte where rn>1
```

As seen pointed out in comments,this deletes a random row (undeterministic),to make it deterministic order by name in your case

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can use:

```
DELETE mytable
FROM mytable
JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, X, Y
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY X, Y
) AS t ON mytable.X =  t.X AND mytable.Y = t.Y AND mytable.ID > t.ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e506c5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Its easy:

Add an INDEX over the 2 Columns with IGNORE:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE YOUR_TABLE
ADD KEY (X,Y);
```

Thats all